# Android, when opening shared location, my map not visible in system choises

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-intent, mime-types

for example, in whatsapp someone send own location and when we click to message system opens choise dialog with map apps that can open location like google map, yandex map and others. I want that my map app also be there. Other words, I want that system recognize my app as map app and when user click to location in whatsapp or other apps my app appear in system choise dialog. How can I configure my app to open location? I searched and in forums and android documentation they recommend to use implicit intent for it. But they dont show how to configure app that shows in system choises. I heard about mime-types but in documentation there are no mime-type for location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) to your `activity` that allows it to respond to map URLs. In your `Androidmanifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maps.google.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" />
    <data android:scheme="geo"/>
</intent-filter>
```

To retrieve the URI:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();  
    Uri data = intent.getData(); // Here you will receive the URI

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio for reply, that is was what i want )) Please, tell me how can retrieve latitude and longitude and zoom level from this Uri?

Comment: You will receive an Uri like `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.3836251,-2.38361628` which means `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=latitude,longitude`

Answer (score 0):

[Implicit Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)'s are more of like *Your app* to *other apps* sort of thing and you're aiming for the reverse version (*Other apps* to *your app*). What you are looking for is [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html). As per the docs:

> To allow other apps to start your activity, you need to add an `<intent-filter>` element in your manifest file for the corresponding `<activity>` element.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for advice :)